# Retrieve data from a table and register it as a model on Django's admin page

Tags: python, django

I'm using APscheduler to schedule some jobs in my app.
I'm using my database as a job store, saving all info in a table named `Jobs`.

Since this table is created and populated by APscheduler, I don't have access to it as a Django model instance (it's not defined in `models.py`).

How can I retrieve data from this table and register it as a model on the admin page?
I've searched the web and found Django's `RawQuery`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since this table is created and populated by `APscheduler`, I don't have access to it as a Django model instance.

You **have**. [**`django-appscheduler`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/jcass77/django-apscheduler) is just a Django app, and it has a [**`models.py`** file [GitHub]](https://github.com/jcass77/django-apscheduler/blob/v0.5.2/django_apscheduler/models.py) with a `DjangoJob` in it.

You thus can import this with:

```
from django_apscheduler.models import DjangoJob
```

and make queries just like you do with another model.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can try like this: first, Create a model named `Job` with fields same as column name. Then in the meta, define the `db_table` field as `Jobs` and add [`managed = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#managed):

```
Class Job(models.Model):
    field_one = models.IntergerField(primary_key=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'Jobs'
       managed = False
```

In that way, you do not have to run migrations/migrate, and you should be able query using that model class.

Comment: That's a great solution! But @WillemVanOnsem [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66276507/12367238) feels more reliable! Thanks for answering!